# Выгрузка dll из процессов

Tags: windows, dll

Имеется процесс `pointblank.exe`.

Надо выгрузить из него dll-ки. Или, по крайней мере, заморозить их.

```
gameShieldDll.dll
frostRecvfrom.dll
gameShieldDll.dll
frostUpdater.dll
```

Скажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Оформи картинку как ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Просто так вы не можете это сделать.. просто отгрузить dll можно, но приложение может разрушиться. Единственный вариант, это проанализировать таблицу экспорта этих dll'ок и сделать поддельные dll-ки, которые ничего не делают, но экспортируют функции, с такими же прототипами. И даже тогда есть шанс всё завалить и это будет не просто.

Если код из этих dll'ок работает в отдельных потоках, то можно попытаться заморозить эти потоки, а dll'ки оставить в покое.

Answer (score 1):

Остано треда в пределах целевого модуля приведёт к зависаниям и дедлокам. Выгрузка эквивалентна завершению процесса, так как будет вызвана процедура инициализации с аналогичной завершению процесса причиной. Разумно использовать заглушки, блокирующие  функционал, можно использовать провайдер верификации.

Answer (score 0):

На ходу этого не сделать! А вот написать новые dll-ки с теми же именами, переименовать старые и новые положить туда же, где лежат старые. В новонаписанных dll-ках должны быть те же функции, что и в старых, но они должны быть пустыми (NOP), тогда прога при обращении к этим функциям получит ответ (NOP), что равносильно выгруженной dll-ке. Они будут в памяти, даже будут работать, но ничего делать не будут. :)